# Android: set background color of radiobutton text programatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiobutton

When i try to change background color of radio button *text* programatically like this:

```
rb.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mycustombackground);
```

The background covers both the button and the text.
I only want to change the background color of the text part (not the radio button).

How to achieve that?

Comment: you have to use setTextColor, why are you changing the background color?

Comment: `setTextColor` changes the color of the letters, changing the background color of just the text part of a view is not supported

Comment: @Blackbelt> becz i really want to change background of the text.

Comment: what does becz mean ?

Comment: @Blackbelt > becz == because :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets see if it works:

```
Spannable span = new SpannableStringBuilder(rb.getText().toString());
span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, rb.getText().toString().length(), SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
rb.setText(span);
```

Replace Color.RED with whichever color you want. Don't forget you have to grab it from the resources if you want it. I don't think it works with drawables.